# Django Channels - не отсылается данные из команды

Tags: python, django, websocket

Создал кастомную консольную команду.
Запускаю ее через python manage.py <имя команды>
Для теста делаю принт в консоль. Команда отрабатывает, но данные по вебсокету не отсылается. Ошибки нет

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    pass

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    date_now = timezone.now()

    # tasks = Task.objects.filter(created_date=date_now)



    print ('Hello')

    Group("notify").send({
        "text": json.dumps({
            "type": 'task',
            "id": 'doer_id',
            "task_id": False,
            "content": False
        })
    },immediately=True)
```

Comment: Небось используете asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer?

Comment: Что значит "Ошибки нет". И какая библиотека импортируется для Group?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, а чем его заменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бэкенд `asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer` используется только для разработки и отладки. Для обмена данными между слоями и обработчиками он использует область памяти процесса, но management commands запускаются в отдельном процессе и доступа к этой области памяти получить не могут. Вам необходимо

1. установить и настроить Redis или другой брокер очередей;
2. установить соответствующий бэкенд командой `pip install -U asgi_redis`;
3. и прописать его в настройках

   ```
   CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
       "default": {
           "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
           "CONFIG": {
               "hosts": [("redis-server-name", 6379)],
           },
           "ROUTING": "my_project.routing.channel_routing",
       },
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, буду копать в эту сторону.